# Can't access from outside process running in a Docker container

Tags: linux, networking, docker, debian

I'm trying to run a gameserver inside a docker container on my server but I'm having troubles connecting to it.

I created my container and started my gameserver (which is using port 7777) inside it.

I'm running the container with this command:

```
docker run -p 7777:7777 -v /home/gameserver/:/home -c=1024 -m=1024m -d --name my_gameserver game
```

I published the ports 7777 with the `-p` parameter but I can't connect to my gameserver, even though logs show that it is started.

I think I should bind my IP in some way but I have no idea what to do.
What I found so far is that `docker inspect my_gameserver | grep IPAddress` returns `172.17.0.24`.

Comment: 172.17.0.24 is private network of docker container;  Seeing the cmd option you binded your host machine ip with port 7777 to the container port 7777 so running localhost:7777 will bind to the container 7777 port;  Running iptable -t nat -L will show that NAT was done internally;  We need now make sure that the port 7777 is hosting the gameserver in the container;

Comment: What address do you try to connect to the server on? Remember you'll need to use the address of the server, not the internal container one.

Comment: @AdrianMouat I'm indeed using my server IP to connect to my gameserver.

Comment: From inside the gameserver or outside? The first step is to see if you can connect to the container from the gameserver, using the IP of the gameserver or localhost.

Comment: @AdrianMouat I'm trying to connect from outside my server. I don't know how can I connect to my gameserver from inside my server or my container.

Comment: Just telnet to the port and see if it responds. The issue is probably just that you need to open a port in a firewall.

Comment: @AdrianMouat `telnet localhost 7777` returns something but `telnet myserverip 7777` returns connection refused.
Also I tried to open all ports using `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT` but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Changes to the iptables `INPUT` chain will not impact access to Docker containers.  Because your host is forwarding packets to your containers, these packets traverse the `FORWARD` chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the fact that I didn't expose the UDP port.
Correct command was:

```
docker run -p 7777:7777 -p 7777:7777/udp -v -d --name my_gameserver game
```